# Excel Pivot Table compare 2 columns for equal values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a single table for billiards with the following columns:
LName, Date Played, Total Wins, Total Games.
I want to create a pivot table for player who have:
played and won 8 games or
played and won 9 games.
These are 100% wins for that day of play. (And they get a plaque)
I don't care about any other numbers some only play 3 games and won 3 games, etc.
These are 8-game and 9-game tournaments.
I want to be able to select all the years that all the players won 8x8 or 9x9 games.
[image: Table Layout with pivot table fields]

Answer (score 1):

Drag another "Total Games" and "Wins-Totals" field into the Filters area. Then filter Wins-Total = 0, and Total Wins = 8 or 9.

[image]